# Can Swagger @ApiOperation allow to specify a list of list in Java?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a method in a Java class with signature like below and I want to add Swagger Rest documentation for it.

```
public List<List<MyCustomClass>> getMyCustomClasses(String id){
//
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to have either response or responseContainer to return List of List objects?
Something like below?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "find MyCustomClass objects by id", response =MyCustomClass.class , responseContainer =   "List<List>")
```

I have no issues in generating swagger docs if the response of the method is just List 
where I could specify response =MyCustomClass.class , responseContainer = "List" but having problem only if it is List of List as return type.

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: Have you tried response = List<MyCustomClass>.class, responseContainer = "List"?

Comment: Thanks James! I tried that as well but it gives compiler error             Syntax error on tokens, PrimitiveType expected instead  I have even tried to create a class level variable like                       private static final Class<List<CustomClass>> customList = null;   and tried to put response=customList and it again gives compile error.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm currently using swagger-core 1.5.8. As a hack, I tried this: @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(message = "Okay", code = 200, response = MyCustomClass[][].class)
    })

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this you can simply create a template class like this:

```
public class TempClass {
   private List<someClass> listOfClass;
   public List<someClass> getListOfClass() {
      return listOfClass;
   }
   public void setListOfClass(List<someClass> listOfClass) {
      this.listOfClass = listOfClass;
   }
}
```

or even more complicated like this:

```
public class TempClass {
   private List<List<List<someClass>>> listOfList;
   public List<List<List<someClass>>> getListOfList(){ 
      return listOfList;
   }
   public void setListOfList(List<List<List<someClass>>> listOfList) {
      this.listOfList = listOfList;
   }
}
```

And at the end get this class as a response to the annotation above the method like this:

```
@ApiOperation(response = TempClass.class)
```

you should also specify the return type of the method as the TempClass

There is another issue that discussed a same issue [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/498#issuecomment-73732315)