# response in swagger's @ApiOperation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

Suppose, if My `response` is `Map<String, List<SomeClass>>`, how to specify that in response field of the code snippet `@ApiResponse(value="", response="")` ? I mean what should I put in `responseContainer` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the json or XML or whatever response your API gives ? I want to see what type of response it actually is ?

Comment: I think you would not need the responseContainer here, and you can try providing `response = Map.class`

Comment: `{  
   "entity":{  
      "2017-04-13":[  
         {  
            "taskPropertyId":69060,
            "title":"task5",
            "taskId":15695,
            "scheduleId":null,
         },
           
         {  
            "taskPropertyId":69064,
            "title":"task9",
            "taskId":15699,
            "scheduleId":null,
         },
           
   "status":200,
   "message":null
}`
Above is the sample response from my API, where `"2017-04-13"` is the key.

Comment: Did you try giving response as Map.class ?

Comment: @gaganbm I think providing `response = Map.class` does not show the response model in the swagger UI.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I'm looking for an answer for similar response handling. But I could find only this [Can Swagger @APIOperation allow to specify a list of list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557640/can-swagger-apioperation-allow-to-specify-a-list-of-list-in-java). Although not convincing but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using swagger 2.9.2 and I have no issue in display of complex data structures in UI.

Suppose you have field "mapOfSets" in your dto class:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "A map of sets", position = 4)
private Map<String, Set<String>> mapOfSets;
```

Then in swagger UI it will be displayed as following:

[image]

2 Maven dependencies are used in our project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```